# Reshape dataframe in R + generate column name

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

my dataframe looks like this

```
df <- read.table(text="
                 id          nr      date
    1            124         1       2017
    2            122         1       2017
    3            124         2       2018
    4            121         1       2017
    5            124         3       2018
", header=TRUE)
```

resoult should be

```
df <- read.table(text="
                 id          number1  number2  number3 
    1            124         2017     2018     2018 
    2            122         2017
    3            121         2017
", header=TRUE)
```

Note that I no need just reshape my table but even egenerate now colnames based on nr column.

Comment: You can do `reshape2::dcast(df, id ~ paste0("number", nr))`

Comment: `reshape(df,direction='wide',timevar='nr',idvar='id',v.names='date',sep='_')` ?